# Probability calculation from joint pdfs

Tags: probability, integration

$f(x, y) = 6x$ for $ 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$

How do I calculate the following probability ? I haven't done double integrals in years and can't understand how this works.

$P(X < 1/2, Y < 1/2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X<1/2,Y<1/2) = \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2}f(x,y)dydx = \int_0^{1/2}\int_x^{1/2}f(x,y)dydx,$$

since $y\geq x$ (otherwise $f(x,y)=0$). Now just evaluate the integrals one at a time. The first one gives $\left.6xy\right|_x^{1/2}$. Can you finish it from here?